# Pass Edge Function that runs in Middleware value to Pages in NextJs

Tags: next.js, middleware

Following the documentation, I have created a _middleware.js file inside the pages folder and written the following code in it.

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function middleware(req, res) {
  const { nextUrl: url, geo } = req;

  const country = geo.country || 'US';
  const city = geo.city || 'San Francisco';

  url.searchParams.set('country', country);
  url.searchParams.set('city', city);

  return NextResponse.rewrite(url);
}
```

I want to get this country and city inside the index.js page. To do this I write the following code in the index.js page.

```
import { serverSideTranslations } from 'next-i18next/serverSideTranslations';
import Home from '../components/Home';

export default function Index({ query }) {
  console.log(query);
  return (
    <div>
      <Home />
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ locale, query }) {

  return {
    props: {
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale)),
      query,
    },
  };
}
```

This is the way it is mentioned in documentation or the way I think it is. But it is not working.

Instead of getting Home Component I am getting 404 NOT FOUND PAGE.

How to resolve this ???

Comment: Does it work without the middleware?

Comment: This works perfectly on localhost. The issue is on production only 
Here is the production test link >> [Link to Live](https://testme-seven.vercel.app/)

Comment: You might ask the Vercel support if this happens only on production.